# regex to reject '_'

Tags: java, regex

I want to reject string which starts with `_`. I have regex to reject `_` if found in string.
`"^[^_]*$"`.

Comment: Please fix the formatting in your question. It is 100% unclear to me what regex you're after.

Answer (score 8):

Do you really need a regex for this?  What about:

```
!myString.startsWith("_")
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `"^[^_].*$"`. That should reject only strings beginning with `_`.

Answer (score 0):

This will match a line of text beginning with an underscore : `^_(.*)$`

This will match a line of text beginning with anything but an underscore: `^[^_](.*)$`